# In .NET, I get a weird "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Double'."

Tags: c#, casting

Houston, I have a problem.

We all know that casting from any `int` to a `double` is implicit. But I have this weird case where it is not.

Check this out, in a console project:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object? o = null;
    double d = (double) ( true ? 0 : o);
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! 'd' is {d:0.00}");
}
```

As we have true, the system should be able to cast the 0 to a double. Well, it does not. I thought maybe because of the null object, but then, if we type 0.0 instead of 0, we get a correct response:

```
internal class Program

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object? o = null;
    double d = (double) ( true ? 0.0 : o);
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! 'd' is {d:0.00}");
}
```

Even if we put a numerical value into the object, it does not work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object o = 0;
    double d = (double) ( true ? 0 : o);
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! 'd' is {d:0.00}");
}
```

Any ideas?

[image: Picture showing to the examples, side by side]

Answer (score 1):

> We all know that casting from any 'int' to a 'double' is implicit. [...] the system should be able to cast the 0 to a double

The trouble with stating what you believe are facts as absolute statements is that it makes you seem (correctly so, in this case) that you blame your tools rather than understanding what the rules of implicit casting are. And since I do know the actual rules of implicit casting, it makes me simply glance over your question, since people like that don't actually want to learn, they want to have their shortcomings validated.

To answer what you actually wanted to ask, you're conflating implicit casting and unboxing. `(double)v` is a cast when `v` is a number type (for example, `int`) and it's an unboxing operation when `v` is a reference type (for example, `object`). And since you can only unbox to the actual boxed value's type, the latter operation will fail.

You can of course combine the two, for example: `double d = (int)(object)0;`. In this case, `0` will be boxed to an `object`, then unboxed successfully to an `int`, then implicitly cast to a double.

Comment: Lord you could have phrased this in a hundred different ways, that would have been both easier to understand, and with less arrogant smugness, you score is high enough, to not need to prove anything, and yet this answer is just .... yuck. Hence the downvote.

Comment: The issue does not stem from boxing/unboxing, as the example with a null value successfully casting to double disproves the notion that boxing/unboxing is the root cause of the problem.
In addition, the error is clear "cannot cast an int32 to a double".
To clarify, both expressions within the ternary conditional operator should return the same type, regardless of one being an object. By explicitly defining both expressions to be of the same type, as demonstrated in the corrected example, the system successfully handles the implicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

Conversions for C# are explained here:
[Conversion rules explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions)

When you do this:

double d = (double) ( true ? 0 : o);

the (double) is not required.

An implicit cast, which you note int to double is, you do not need to be explicit about the type you wish your origin to be cast to.

This will compile and execute:

```
 int i = 0;
 int i2 = 1;
 double d = (true ? i2 : i);
 Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! 'd' is {d:0.00}");
```

This is implicit conversion.

In your code the cast is making your code explicit. (And yet the code still fails)

When you provide an object reference you are unboxing.
You are casting by value, not reference when you implicitly use an object in code. This is where it breaks your logic, as it will only allow the value type to be used. (It will assume that your object is of your first parameter type, either int or double depending on which example you execute)

And which ever value is present will be the expected value unboxed for the object type. This will prevent the implicit casting from reference, because it is already locked in a casting from value.

Thus you get an exception. You can see this rule and many other in the documentation provided in the link.

Comment: I understand, for this I have added two screenshots, both codes hold an object initialized to null, and a conditional operator that explicitly converts whatever result to double.
The condition is always 'true', hence the first expression should return. The first expression is an int, so it has no problem to be casted either implicitly or explicitly to a double. 
The only difference is that when the first expression is a double, it works, when it is an int it does not. And the error is clear: "Cannot cast int32 to double", but  we all know that such casting is possible.

Comment: Yes the casting is possible, but because the entire statement is considered an explicit conversion due to the compiler deciding which return type is the required return type. You cannot expect an implicit conversion to work, in the same statement.